# How to fill a column in bootstrap with full height background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the column at left to be completely filled with a background-color regardless of the column height. 
Someone having a resolution to this issue?

Example:

[image: Picutre]

My HTML is:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="span8">
 </div>
 <div class="span4">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which div element is your background?

Comment: I don't think i understood your question @KeesSonnema

Answer (score 0):

Just make a div for the left column

```
<div id="coloredcolumn">
    empty div at the left
    </div>

    #coloredcolumn{
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }
```

You want this? when i understand right.

Comment: It does not always work. i think indeed that the best way for this is javascript. so see the question above me.